# Color a specific cell in a java JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I want to color a specific cell on a JTable by entering row number and column number.

For example, I have this code that meant to color the first cell row =0 , column =0 but it is not working

```
package functions_classes;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class RemoveAddRows extends JFrame {

     static DefaultTableCellRenderer stringRenderer;
     static Component c;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Object[] columnNames = {"Type", "Company", "Shares", "Price"};
    private Object[][] data = {
        {"Buy", "IBM", Integer.valueOf(1000), Double.valueOf(80.50)},
        {"Sell", "MicroSoft", Integer.valueOf(2000), Double.valueOf(6.25)},
        {"Sell", "Apple", Integer.valueOf(3000), Double.valueOf(7.35)},
        {"Buy", "Nortel", Integer.valueOf(4000), Double.valueOf(20.00)}
    };
    public static JTable table;

    private DefaultTableModel model;
    private javax.swing.Timer timer = null;

    public RemoveAddRows() {
        model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };

        table = new JTable(model) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column) {
                 c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);                     
                 System.out.println("la valeur de row egale "+row);                     
                 System.out.println("la valeur de column egale "+column);
                if (isRowSelected(0) && isColumnSelected(0)) {
                   // ((JComponent) c).setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
                    ((JComponent) c).setBackground(Color.RED);
                    }                      
                return c;
            }
        };

        stringRenderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer) table.getDefaultRenderer(String.class);
        stringRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        ListSelectionModel rowSelMod = table.getSelectionModel();

        rowSelMod.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
                int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                int col = table.getSelectedColumn();
                String str = "Selected Row(s): ";
                int[] rows = table.getSelectedRows();
                for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    str += rows[i] + " ";
                }
                str += "Selected Column(s): ";
                int[] cols = table.getSelectedColumns();
                for (int i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
                    str += cols[i] + " ";
                }
                str += "Selected Cell: " + table.getSelectedRow() + ", " + table.getSelectedColumn();
                System.out.println(str);
                Object value = table.getValueAt(row, col);
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(value));
            }
        });
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Remove all rows");
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (model.getRowCount() > 0) {
                    for (int i = model.getRowCount() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                        model.removeRow(i);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("model.getRowCount() --->" + model.getRowCount());
            }
        });
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Add new rows");
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                start();
            }
        });
        JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
        southPanel.add(button1);
        southPanel.add(button2);
        add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private void start() {
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(2500, updateCol());
        timer.start();
    }

    public Action updateCol() {
        return new AbstractAction("text load action") {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                Object[] data0 = {"Buy", "IBM", Integer.valueOf(1000), Double.valueOf(80.50)};
                model.addRow(data0);
                Object[] data1 = {"Sell", "MicroSoft", Integer.valueOf(2000), Double.valueOf(6.25)};
                model.addRow(data1);
                Object[] data2 = {"Sell", "Apple", Integer.valueOf(3000), Double.valueOf(7.35)};
                model.addRow(data2);
                Object[] data3 = {"Buy", "Nortel", Integer.valueOf(4000), Double.valueOf(20.00)};
                model.addRow(data3);
                System.out.println("model.getRowCount() --->" + model.getRowCount());
                timer.stop();
                int rowIndex = table.getRowCount() - 1;
                table.changeSelection(rowIndex, 0, false, false);
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                RemoveAddRows frame = new RemoveAddRows();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);                    

             //   table.prepareRenderer(stringRenderer, 1, 2);
                //Component c1=table.prepareRenderer((DefaultTableCellRenderer) table.getDefaultRenderer(String.class), 1,1);

               // stringRenderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer) table.getDefaultRenderer(String.class);
               // JComponent c1=(JComponent) table.prepareRenderer(stringRenderer, 0,0);
                // c1.setBackground(Color.cyan);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: everything depends of if based on value in the cell or coordinates

Comment: isRowSelected(0) && isColumnSelected(0) is wrong, this is coordinates whats happend if is selected, more see answer by @SilverHaze, btw answering your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if (isRowSelected(0) && isColumnSelected(0)) {
   // ((JComponent) c).setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red));
   ((JComponent) c).setBackground(Color.RED);
}
```

Use this piece of code:

```
c.setBackground((row == 0) && (column == 0) ? Color.RED : Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: use c.setBackground((row == 0) && (column == 0) ? Color.RED : table.getBackground());

Answer (score 4):

You will need to implement a custom cell renderer to do this, I've adapted some old code of mine. Hopefully this should work, I've checked that it compiles, but I haven't tested it;

```
import javax.swing.JTable; 
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer; 
import java.awt.Component;  
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ColorCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    class Coordinate
    {
        public int row, col;
        public Coordinate(int row, int col)
        {
            this.row=row;this.col=col;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o)
        {
            if(o instanceof Coordinate)
            {
                return (((Coordinate)o).row==this.row)&&(((Coordinate)o).col==this.col);
            }
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode()
        {//Unique until col 10000
            return col + row*10000;
        }
    }
    private HashMap<Coordinate, Color> colorMap;
    public ColorCellRenderer() { 
        super();
        colorMap = new HashMap<Coordinate, Color>();
    } 
    public Color setColor(int row, int col, Color c)
    {
        return colorMap.put(new Coordinate(row, col), c);
    }
    /** 
     * Returns the component used for drawing the cell.  This method is 
     * used to configure the renderer appropriately before drawing. 
     * 
     * @param table      - JTable object 
     * @param value      - the value of the cell to be rendered. 
     * @param isSelected - isSelected   true if the cell is to be rendered with the selection highlighted; 
     *                   otherwise false. 
     * @param hasFocus   - if true, render cell appropriately. 
     * @param row        - The row index of the cell being drawn. 
     * @param column     - The column index of the cell being drawn. 
     * @return - Returns the component used for drawing the cell. 
     */ 

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent
    (
        JTable table,
        Object value, 
        boolean isSelected, 
        boolean hasFocus, 
        int row, 
        int column
    ) 
        {
            Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            //Get color from nested hashmap
            //We allow it to setBackground(null) as DefaultRenderer doesn't resetBackground when called again.
                if(isSelected){
                    c.setBackgroun(table.getSelectionBackground());
                }else{
                    c.setBackground(colorMap.get(new Coordinate(row, column)));
            }
                return c; 
        } 
}
```

Comment: beware: this implementation will run into the infamous color-memory of DTCR if no color is found. To make it work correctly, the color must be set always. Can be done by f.i. by setting the background before calling super: set to custom if color found, null if not found

Comment: I don't follow? This method takes the component generated by the default cell renderer and then sets the background if there is one stored in the HashMap, otherwise it doesn't. That should be safe as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ah, after researching what you've said, basically the renderer doesn't re-set the background colour when it is recalled, so I should set it to `NULL` if not colour is taken from the map. Thanks, I've fixed this now in the code.

Comment: on the way to the upvote, though not yet entirely there (my pedantic day ;-) - this will loose selection (or any other color marker super has applied) in the cells without custom color. Repeating: do it _before_ calling super and you're safe.

Comment: You make a good point, however you are incorrect about placing it before (I've checked the source `super.setBackground(bg == null ? table.getSelectionBackground(): bg)`) as it will not apply the selection colour unless bg isn't already set. However I've added that to my code so it will now apply selection colour. It is unnecessary for focus as that only applies a border. Thanks again

Comment: your finding isn't contradicting my last comment, just another requirement :-) Check again: I was talking about keeping selection (or others, like f.i. drop over) if there is _no_ custom color, you solve the requirement to have selection always, custom color or not. Anyway, good answer, +1

Comment: Already hit rep limit for the day, makes no diff :(
Thanks for your input, still waiting for a chance to pull out the wrapable header cell renderer and wrapable cell renderer, they took quite a bit of trial and error to make work :D

Answer (score -1):

`JComponent` does not know how to set its background.
Instead, you should manually paint the colour on the component.

I suggest you create your own component:

```
private class CustomComponent extends JComponent{
    CustomComponent() {
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(getBackground());
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
```

}

You can do `isSelected` validation inside your custom component, and set the colour accordingly.

Comment: where i put row and column ?

Comment: that's simply wrong: all _Components_ have a background property. Whether it's painted or not depends on its opacity property

Comment: I've encountered an issue that even when you `setOpaque(true)`, it still doesn't paint the background as it should.

Comment: ahh ... I see what you are saying: indeed JComponent itself doesn't do anything - painting is delegated to its ui. So a custom component either needs a UI (best option) or take over the background painting itself as you suggest in your answer. Just: the question here isn't about a direct subclass (any concrete child in Swing has-a ui), consider clarifying :-)